# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tagit'

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, tag-it

please any one help me to come out from the issue.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
        $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            allowSpaces: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

i got an error in the place of `$('#allowSpacesTags').tagit`

Comment: do you have the **[`.tagit`](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)** plugin loaded alongside **jQuery**?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have correct implementation of Tag-it, a jQuery UI plugin?
https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#usage

Comment: Yes Adam, i used the same what you are mentioned here. i have a doubt on my website has master page. it has jQuery reference which is lower version of which i given reference to the child page

Comment: so is it possible to conflict? adam

Comment: VetriJith which version you have on your child page? Can you show me your libraries implementation